# c program to see if value is correct or not

Tags: c

Write a C program, that reads messages from an input file (or stdin) and verifies whether the messages are valid or not.

How would put the delimiter in the input file because right now it looks like this:
Input file:

```
:E201022011101F
:P
:PBCBCBC
:Q7
:Q66666676666
:Q76767
:M84E2010201F
:M27PBC
```

This is my code and it's correct however I keep getting Segmentation fault (core dumped).
How can I solve this error?
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
bool foo(char msg[120]);
bool eep(char msg[120]);
bool op(char msg[120]);
bool ork(char msg[120]);
void main()
{
char fname[30],lyne[120];

FILE *filehandle;
char *item;
char rule[100],msg[120];
printf("Enter the filename");
scanf("%s",fname);
filehandle = fopen(fname, "r");
if (filehandle == NULL)
{
printf("Error Could not open");
return;
}


while (fgets(lyne,120,filehandle)) {
//printf("%s",lyne);
item = strtok(lyne,":");
strcpy( rule,item);
//printf("%s",rule);
item = strtok(NULL,":");
strcpy( msg,item);
if(strcmp(rule,"foo")==0)
{
printf("\nMessage: %s",msg);
if(foo(msg))
{
//strcat(msg," OK");
printf("OK");
}
else
{
//strcat(msg," FAIL");
printf("FAIL");
}

}
/* if(strcmp(rule,"eep")==0)
{

if(eep(msg))
{
printf("OK\n");


}
else
{
printf("FAIL\n");
}
}*/
if(strcmp(rule,"op")==0)
{
printf("\nMessage: %s",msg);
if(op(msg))
{
//strcat(msg," OK");
printf("OK");
}
else
{
//strcat(msg," FAIL");
printf("FAIL");
}


}
/*
if(strcmp(rule,"ork")==0)
{
if(ork(msg))
{


printf("OK\n");
}
else
{
printf("FAIL\n");
}
}*/


// printf("msg: %s",msg);
}


}

bool foo(char msg[120])
{
int len;
len=strlen(msg);
int valid1=0,valid2=0;
int i;
// printf("%c last %c",msg[0],msg[(len-3)]);
// printf("%d",len);
// for(i=0;i<len;i++)
// {
// printf("%c",msg[i]);
//}
if(msg[0]=='E' && msg[len-3]=='F') // please check the correct character position and take
{
valid1=1;

}
for(i=1;i<=len-4;i++)
{
if(msg[i]=='0'||msg[i]=='1'||msg[i]=='2')
{
valid2=1;
}
else
{
valid2=0;
}
// printf("\n%d %c",i,msg[i]);
}
if(valid1==1 && valid2==1)
{
return true;
}
//printf("%d%d",valid1,valid2);
return false;
}
bool eep(char msg[120])
{
bool v1=false;
if(msg[0]=='P')
{
// v1=true;
}

return false;
}
bool op(char msg[120])
{
int l;
bool v1=false,v2=false,v3=true;
int i;
int c=0;
l=strlen(msg);
// printf("%d",l);
if(msg[0]=='Q')
{
v1=true;
}
for(int i=1;i<l-2;i++)
{
if(msg[i]=='6'||msg[i]=='7')
{
v2=true;
}
else
{
v2=false;
}
if(msg[i]=='7')
{
c++;
}
}
if(c%2==1)
{
v3=true;
}
if(v1=true && v2==true && v3==true)
{
return true;
}

return false;
}
bool ork(char msg[120])
{
return false;
}
```

I'm doing this on putty and this is what the output should look like:

[image]

Comment: Please check the return value from `strtok()`. The example file does not contain the delimiter passed to `strtok()` so it can only be called once per line. Then it returns `NULL`.

Comment: The initial `:` will be skipped by `strtok()` and the second call will return `NULL`. The function does not create "empty" strings.